# Jquery $.ajax with dataType parse error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

*I have went through the other questions related to my issue but the solutions dint work for me*. This is my ajax code:

```
   $.ajax({
     url:'http://localhost:8080/items?callback=?',
     type:'GET',
     //the name of the callback function
     jsonp: "jsonpcallback",
     dataType:'jsonp',

     success:function(data){
        alert("hello" + data);
         var length = data.length;
         for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
           var object = data[i];
           var item = new Item(object.id,object.name,object.price,object.quantity);
           $("#items-container").append(getItemHtml(item.id));

         }

     },
     error:function(xhr,status,error){
        alert(status);
     }
 });
```

This is my **callback function:**

```
function jsonpcallback(data){
 console.log(data);
}
```

I am getting a error called parse error. can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong??? Response coming from the server doesn't have any errors.

**Edit:**
Added server response:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Snickers",
    "price": 1.5,
    "quantity": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "M&M's",
    "price": 1.25,
    "quantity": 8
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Almond Joy",
    "price": 1.25,
    "quantity": 11
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Milky Way",
    "price": 1.65,
    "quantity": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Payday",
    "price": 1.75,
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Reese's",
    "price": 1.5,
    "quantity": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Pringles",
    "price": 2.35,
    "quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Cheezits",
    "price": 2,
    "quantity": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Doritos",
    "price": 1.95,
    "quantity": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: Parse error where? At least tell us what line it's referring to

Comment: I am getting it inside error function! when status is shown using alert it says parse error

Comment: Are you sure you're returning JSONP data, not JSON? Seeing the response text and/or server side code would help here

Comment: can you also add part of your response code? it is possibly related to your response data.

Comment: jsonp is not a data model. you pass it with your ajax request and wrap your json data with it. so when you send a request like yours, your data response should return jsonpcallback({"data":"value".....})

Comment: jsonp is just json with padding right??server is returning a json data . I am not get it using normal ajax method as it is throwing cross domain permission denied so I am using jsonp

Comment: if you are getting cross domain permission error than I assume you don't have access to that domain, as well as that data. in order to use jsonp data you should either have crossdomain.xml in server to give access to return that data to your domain, or you can add jsonp request and wrap json data with your callback function.

Comment: I have added the server response

Comment: I am sure the permissions are enabled on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of your call is JSON, not JSONP. They are not interchangeable. To fix this set `dataType` to `'json'` and remove references to JSONP callbacks. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/items',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // only for testing

    var length = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      var object = data[i];
      var item = new Item(object.id, object.name, object.price, object.quantity);
      $("#items-container").append(getItemHtml(item.id));
    }
  },
  error:function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(status);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting cross-domain permission denied error when I do this. but the server has enabled cross-domain permissions

Comment: You say you've added cross-domain permissions, but they cannot be working correctly for you to have that error. You need to add CORS headers on the response.

Comment: Hey I changed my code to your answer I am not getting any cross-domain errors but I am still getting  the parse error

Comment: Apologies - I missed removing the `callback` querystring parameter. Try now

Comment: If you check the network tab of the console you should be able to see the failed request which should give you a far more detailed error description than the jQuery `alert()` is.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/items. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '//localhost:8080'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. this is what I am seeing

Comment: That means your CORS headers are not set correctly. I'd suggest starting a new question about how you've defined them in your server side code. The JS itself is fine.